# Why doesn't JavaScript recognize erb as valid 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash, erb

I have this:

```
<% citys = { "New York" => 200, "Boston" => 300, "Miami" => 400, "Chicago" => 500, "Los Angeles" => 600, "Houston" => 700 } %>

function drawMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', 'Popularity'],
    <% citys.each do |key, value| %>
       [<% key %>, <% value %>], 
    <% end %>
  ]);
```

But it says it's not recognized as a valid 2D array. What's wrong here?

Comment: That looks like trouble at first glance. Try using JSON and looping _in JavaScript_. Check here http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the JavaScript you are generating. Don't look at the template and compare that to how the browser reacts.

JavaScript string literals must be quoted. You aren't outputting quotes around the strings you are outputting.

Also, trailing commas will cause problems in some JavaScript engines. You are outputting a comma after the last entry.